# conversion to non-scalar type in an iteration over a vector inside a set

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a set of vectors of pointer. I try to iterate over a selected vector from the set.

The code does not compile as there is a conversion from `* const*` to non-scalar type `**`.

`error: conversion from ‘__normal_iterator<Foo* const*,[...]>’ to non-scalar type ‘__normal_iterator<Foo**,[...]>’ requested`

I read that this is because since c++11 set has no non-constant iterators ([C++ Error: Conversion to Non-Scalar Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273714/c-error-conversion-to-non-scalar-type)). But I don't know how to cast it so that it would work.

A minimal code which shows the error

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
  int v;
};

int main() {
  set<vector<Foo *>> setVecF;
  vector<Foo *> vecF;
  Foo * f = new Foo;

  vecF.push_back(f);
  setVecF.insert(vecF);

  set<vector<Foo *>>::iterator sit(setVecF.begin());
// the line below does not compile  
//vector<Foo *>::iterator vit = sit->begin();
  return 0;
}
```

I expect that `vit` would point at the beginning of the selected vector inside the set, so that I could iterate over it. But it does not as I cannot use `->begin()` on `sit`. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: `set::iterator` and `set::const_iterator` may be (aliases of) the same type.   You are assuming incorrectly they are distinct types, and that `set::iterator` is a non-`const` iterator.   So `sit` is of type `const_iterator` and dereferencing it (using its `operator->()`) gives a `const` object.   A `std::vector::iterator` cannot be obtained from a `const vector`.

Comment: Use auto: `auto vit = sit->begin();`